# How to submit "form-data" in ADF "Web" activity POST call

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to move data from a RESTFul API running on my on-prem application to ADB with ADF. I have installed self-paced IR in my private network to run the activity/pipeline. Now in one of my
API requires form-data to submit in POST call. Equivalent Postman looks like below

[image]

How to perform the same in ADF (As I will be running in self-paced IR dataflow is not applicable)? I am trying with "Web" Activity but dont know how to pass form data in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to pass form data in your ADF's Web Activity as you have selected incorrect method in Web activity:
[image: Highlighted method parameter]

You can select POST method from the dropdown as such:
[image: method parameter dropdown]

After this you will get a place to add request body.

Also to get same effect of selecting form-data in postman, you can set 2 cookies as:
Content-Length: **length of your request body in bytes**
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary= **some value as boundary**

[Content-Type header reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)